# Qual a utilidade da camada de serviço no laravel?

Tags: laravel, orientação-a-objetos, mvc

Qual a real utilidade de uma camada de serviço na estrutura do Laravel?

Tem a ver apenas com separar o código do Controller?

Como utilizar essa camada corretamente?

Minha maior dúvida é se vale a pena aumentar a quantidade de código numa aplicação de médio porte para entrar com a camada de serviço. Muitas vezes partes pequenas de código podem ser escritas no próprio controller para inserir/atualizar/excluir um registro. Só que me incomoda acessar diretamente o banco no controller, então uso services.

Mas, penso que se uma parte da aplicação usa um ou mais services para realizar operações no banco de acordo com a regra de negócio, todas as outras partes da aplicação também devem usar, isso inclui aquelas actions que tem apenas uma linha. Estou pensando errado? Devo utilizar serviços somente em actions mais complexas (por exemplo, um cadastro de usuário)?

Estou sentindo que meus códigos estão ficando mais verbosos por conta disso.

Por exemplo, para atualizar um nome de um usuário, eu simplesmente poderia fazer:

```
function update(User $user) {
   $user->name = 'Foo';
   $user->save();
}
```

Mas, em vez disso faço:

```
  function update(User $user) {
    $this->userService->updateUser($user); //Aqui aplico a regra de negócio, num outro método em outra classe, que talvez nem fosse necessária
}
```

O que seria mais correto?

Comment: Realmente não precisa principalmente se for para fazer métodos que já existem. Eu acho que a camada de `Model` Eloquent já faz o que precisa e é suficiente. A única coisa que utilizo é simplificar dentro do `Model` as chamadas de filtros, ordernações, junções etc ... ou seja, consigo resolver tudo na mesma classe, em vez de instanciar outra ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom dia,

Vou da minha opinião, mas acredito que o caminho pra você é entender porque dividimos os código e porque dividimos como dividimos.

Nesse seu exemplo você só transfere os dados do controller para o serviço e lá no serviço trata os dados pra persistir, o que não traz ganho aparente, ao que parece seu serviço é destinado a persistencia dos dados no banco, o que quer dizer que ele não deveria tratar nenhuma regra e sim persistir os dados apenas, nesse caso específico você poderia tratar os dados no controller e só usar o serviço pra persistir.

Outra Vantagem é a Injeção de dependência, você por exemplo pode fazer esse serviço implementar um Interface de Persistencia, e assim substituir a persistencia diretamente no construtor da classe, um exemplo muito bom é a implementação de Testes Unitários, se você quer testar essa function, como ela está, obrigatoriamente tem que persistir no banco de dados toda vez que rodar os testes, porém se você tiver no objeto $this->userService um objeto recebido como parametro na construção da classe (injeção de dependencia), facilmente você pode substituir a classe injetada por uma classe que simula a persistência.

Este é só um exemplo, existem outros muitos benefícios, alem dos citados, claro.

Para algumas pessoas, vários arquivos separados, e funções pequenas podem parecer verbosos e desnecessários, principalmente porque tentamos pensar como a maquina diferenciaria o código, e sentimos que estamos gastando 10 linhas para fazer o que a maquina entenderia em 1, porém não precisamos escrever codigo pensando na máquina, mas sim nas pessoas que vão ler esse código, tente sempre imaginar uma classe ou função sendo lida por um ser humano, totalmente isolada do código e do contexto, se não der pra entender o que a função faz em um cenário desses então não é um bom código, não esqueça que programadores passam muito mais tempo lendo código do que escrevendo, então é na leitura que temos que nós concentrar.

Um resumo muito legal sobre Clean Code:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9w3o9NHXqu0&list=PLMdYygf53DP5Sc6yFYs6ZmjsuuA2fu0TK

Answer (score 1):

Bem, acho que a grande vantagem dessa camada, é realmente em tornar o seu código bem mais reutilizável e sólido. Isso em relação às funcionalidades de sua aplicação estarem bem divididas, em classes com comportamento bem definidos, e métodos que fazem exatamente sua tarefa específica.

Como por exemplo no seu código acima, onde o `Controller` apenas faz uma manipulação da tarefa a ser executada, obténdo o retorno por meia de um classe de `Servico`, que como o nome próprio nome diz, apenas deve possuir os serviços relacionados àquela entidade no caso `User`.

Dessa forma, caso em outro momento você precise executar algum serviço relacionado à entidade, poderá fazer uso diretamente da classe que contém os Serviços da entidade, assim tornando o seu código bem mais reutilizável.

Espero que isso tenha sido útil.